# switch development mode and product mode by environments in Angular 5

Tags: angular-cli, ng-build

My `angular-cli.json` has environments array.

```
"environmentsSource": "environments/environment.ts"
"environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
```

In `environment.ts`,

```
export const environment = {
      production: false
};
```

In `environment.prod.ts`

```
export const environment = {
      production: true
};
```

And in `main.ts`,

```
if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}
```

However I only have one `package.josn` file.

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build"
```

I have different environments such as dev/qa and prod. The urls are different, how can I switch the mode for just one package.json file?

The build and deploy process is automatedly. We can't change the setting when build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main.ts`, I checked the value of `document.location.host`. If it contains a specific substring then I

```
enableProdMode()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the `configuration` in the CLI.

Example to run the prod environment.

```
ng serve --configuration=prod
```

This will replace the `environment.ts` file by `environment.prod.ts`.

You can set all the needed variable (url, ...) in the environments files.

In the code, you only need to read the environment file. It will be replaced by the angular CLI configuration param. You can parameter this in `angular.json` file.

```json
"configurations": {
    "prod": {
        "fileReplacements": [
            {
                "replace": "apps/afh/src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "apps/afh/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I check in the code and deploy it into server. The machine does not know the environment. Only the user can see the difference from the url. Your code is always setting the prod mode even in dev url.

Comment: @Hello I don't understand clearly your problem. If you don't add the --configuration parameter, it will be dev environment.

Comment: I updated the question, the build/deploy server will read the configuration. It is either dev or prod. I mean I just check in one file into source server, I can't set one parameter for dev and  set another parameter for prod. They are using the same parameter because of the same source file(package.json). It is automated build process.

Comment: In your example, `ng serve --configuration=prod`. It is always prod mode even in dev. I can't set the configuration for dev with another parameter. The package.json file must be same in any envoirments.

Comment: @Hello You can have one `package.json` if you set : `"start": "ng serve", "start:prod": "ng serve --prod"`. You can't the line code to run the project ?

Comment: How do you distinguish them? Say for dev url is `http://mysitedev.com/` and prod url is `http://mysiteprod.com`, and in localhost it is just `localhist:5000`. How do you know their mapping?